# Sort a Dataset in visualbasic

Tags: vb.net

I don't know what i doing wrong. I have been on several forums trying to figure out how to sort a table in visual basic.
I have treid with and with out a dataview, but noting seams to work.

I have a logg that the user can do new inserts in. It has 3 columns. "Date", "Tool", "Comment".
When my VB application loads the program reads the table from a Access database and i get my sorting just fine by the sql phrase:

```
"select * from Logg ORDER BY Logg.Datum DESC"
```

After a user have uppdated the table i whant to sort it again. I have treid the following, but nothing happens. The order is the same whatever i do.

DS is my Dataset and dw my dataview, and "Datum" the column i whant to sort

```
        DS.Tables("hela").DefaultView.Sort = "Datum DESC"
        dw = DS.Tables("hela").DefaultView
        For i = 0 To antal_poss - 1
            LOGG(i, 0) = dw.Table.Rows(i).Item(3)
            LOGG(i, 1) = dw.Table.Rows(i).Item(1)
            LOGG(i, 2) = dw.Table.Rows(i).Item(4)
        Next i
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use the DataView to retrieve the Table and then the DataRows, but you extract them following the order on the DataTable.

You need to loop following the order of the DataView.
Something like this

```
   Dim i As Integer = 0
   For Each row As DataRowView in dw
        LOGG(i, 0) = row.Item(3)
        LOGG(i, 1) = row.Item(1)
        LOGG(i, 2) = row.Item(4)
        i += 1
    Next i
```

Of course this assume that your LOGG array contains enough entries to accomodate every row retrieved.  It is the same number of the rows in the DataTable